# libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 shared library not found when opening gedit

Tags: boot, shared-library

Also my Ubuntu don't boot anymore. 
I already installed the package at-spi2-atk with no avail. I think this package should install that lib on my system.
I don't know if it's related to the boot problem, but i'm guessing it is.

OS: *12.04LTS*

**EDIT:**

Thank you for those who tried to help me out. 
I accidentally mistyped the ubuntu version. It's actually `Precise Pangolin` version.
Anyway, I had it upgraded to 13.04. I'll still try to reproduce the issue later on though. So if anyone has a recommendation, please reopen the the question. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be indicating that your system was upgraded to 13.04 *since* you last experienced this problem. Are you still having the problem, since the upgrade? If so, please add the output of `apt-cache policy libatk-bridge2.0-0` to your question. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: @EliahKagan Since my desktop wasn't working anyway I decided to give 13.04 a chance. Now I'm not experiencing the problem (though other bugs came out, which I resolved). But I still would like to know how can I solve that issue if it happens again. It occured when I was installing the latest Gimp version from source and I needed a bunch of libraries updated and some others which I hadn't installed. So somewhere in the way I shall have corrupted or uninstalled a package and so the problem described above happened. Thanks for helping.